# How can I run commands in a running container in AWS ECS using Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ecs, aws-fargate

If I am running container in AWS ECS using EC2, then I can access running container and execute any command.

ie.
`docker exec -it <containerid> <command>`

How can I run commands in the running container or access container in AWS ECS using Fargate?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Update(16 March, 2021):**

AWS [announced](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/03/amazon-ecs-now-allows-you-to-execute-commands-in-a-container-running-on-amazon-ec2-or-aws-fargate/) a new feature called **ECS Exec** which provides the ability to exec into a running container on Fargate or even those running on EC2. This feature makes use of AWS Systems Manager(SSM) to establish a secure channel between the client and the target container. This detailed blog [post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/new-using-amazon-ecs-exec-access-your-containers-fargate-ec2/) from Amazon describes how to use this feature along with all the prerequisites and the configuration steps.

**Original Answer:**

With Fargate you don't get access to the underlying infrastructure so `docker exec` doesn't seem possible. The documentation doesn't mention this explicitly but it's mentioned in this [Deep Dive into AWS Fargate presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/deep-dive-into-aws-fargate-88065990) by Amazon where this is mentioned on slide 19:

> Some caveats: can’t exec into the container, or access the underlying
> host (this is also a good thing)

There's also some discussion about it on this [open issue](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/issues/143) in ECS CLI github project.

You could try to run an SSH server inside a container to get access but I haven't tried it or come across anyone doing this. It also doesn't seem like a good approach so you are limited there.

Answer (score 5):

You need to provide a "Task role" for a Task Definition (this is different than the "Task execution role"). This can be done by first going to IAM

## IAM role creation

1. IAM > roles > create role
2. custom trust policy > copy + paste

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

3. Add permission > Create Policy
4. JSON > replace YOUR_REGION_HERE & YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID_HERE & CLUSTER_NAME > copy + paste

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:YOUR_REGION_HERE:YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID_HERE:log-group:/aws/ecs/CLUSTER_NAME:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

5. Give it a name
6. go back to Add permissions > search by name > check > Next
7. Give a role name > create role

## ECS new task

1. go back to ECS > go to task definition and create a new revision
2. select your new role for "Task role" (different than "Task execution role") > update Task definition
3. go to your service > update > ensure revision is set to latest > finish update of the service
4. current task and it should auto provision your new task with its new role.
5. try again

## Commands I used to exec in

> enables execute command

`aws ecs update-service --cluster CLUSTER_NAME --service SERVICE_NAME --region REGION --enable-execute-command --force-new-deployment`

> adds ARN to environment for easier cli. Does assume only 1 task running for the service, otherwise just manually go to ECS and grab arn and set them for your cli

`TASK_ARN=$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster CLUSTER_NAME --service SERVICE_NAME --region REGION --output text --query 'taskArns[0]')`

> see the task,

`aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster CLUSTER_NAME --region REGION --tasks $TASK_ARN`

> exec in

`aws ecs execute-command --region REGION --cluster CLUSTER_NAME --task $TASK_ARN --container CONTAINER --command "sh" --interactive`

Answer (score 1):

AWS Fargate is a managed service and it makes sense not to allow access into containers. 
If you need to troubleshoot the container you can always increase the log level of your app running in containers. Best practices on working with containers says

> "Docker containers are in fact immutable. This means that a running
>   container never changes because in case you need to update it, the
>   best practice is to create a new container with the updated version of
>   your application and delete the old one."

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As on 16 March 2021, AWS has introduced ECS Exec which can be used to run command on container running in either EC2 or Fargate.
URL will be available at
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/03/amazon-ecs-now-allows-you-to-execute-commands-in-a-container-running-on-amazon-ec2-or-aws-fargate/

Comment: What you mean "has not"?

Comment: Sorry and thanks for highlighting.. Changed it to "has"