# Run CLI command on ECS Fargate container

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

How is it possible to run a CLI command within a container that's using ECS/Fargate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to SSH into FARGATE manged container instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310447/is-it-possible-to-ssh-into-fargate-manged-container-instances)

Comment: It is possible to run SSHD based on those answers, although that's generally not something you want to have to do with Fargate.

Comment: What have you tried? What minimal context can you provide for running a CLI command in Fargate?

Comment: If it is a one time command at container start you can try using environment variables with an entrypoint, put the environment variables in a secure location like secerts manager or ssm parameters of aws

Comment: 2021: it IS possible to connect to a container running on ECS Fargate. Read this: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/03/amazon-ecs-now-allows-you-to-execute-commands-in-a-container-running-on-amazon-ec2-or-aws-fargate/

Answer (score 3):

DEPRECATED: As mentioned on this answer ([How can I run commands in a running container in AWS ECS using Fargate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51570928/how-can-i-run-commands-in-a-running-container-in-aws-ecs-using-fargate)) you cannot do it due to the fact AWS doesn't give you access to the underlying infrastructure.

UPDATE: Pierre below mentions an announcement from AWS allowing to do just that.

Comment: 2021: it IS possible now: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/03/amazon-ecs-now-allows-you-to-execute-commands-in-a-container-running-on-amazon-ec2-or-aws-fargate/

Answer (score 3):

AWS have now launched Amazon ECS Exec, which allows you to directly interact with containers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html.

Comment: A few requirements to this though: If using AWS CLI, only v1 is supported not v2. Only work on new tasks, not existing tasks.

Answer (score 1):

As i know and having experience on ECS you are not allowed to do it. aws does not give you access to the underlying resources.

if you are using fargate + EC2 Configuration then also it is not to access EC2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are trying to achieve, but if you want you can run a command on a new container that you instantiate for the occasion through a CloudWatch Rule

It will be enough to create a new task definition and indicate the command to execute (in the example executing a Laravel command)

```
ECSReputationSchedulerTask:
  Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  Properties:
    Cpu: 256
    ExecutionRoleArn: !ImportValue ECSTaskExecutionRole
    Family: TaskDefinitionFamily
    Memory: 512
    NetworkMode: awsvpc
    RequiresCompatibilities:
      - FARGATE
    ContainerDefinitions:
      -
        Command:
          - "php"
          - "/home/application/artisan"
          - "execute:operation"
        Name: 'MySchedulerContainer'
        ...
```

and then reference it into a CloudWatch rule (unfortunately this can't be done via CloudFormation yet)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to script your container to execute a cli command, but you cannot ssh into the container though. 
If you can invoke a `.sh` file from the `CMD` command in the Dockerfile, the cli command will get executed as long as you have aws-cli installed on the docker image.

In the Dockerfile make sure to run `pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user` before you invoke your script that contains cli commands.

As an alternative, you can use [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) for Python or the [AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/), which both have comprehensive documentation and enable you to run all the commands you could have run via cli